# Canonical coordinates of first order differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, lie-groups, infinitesimals

Consider the first order differential equation 
\begin{align}
\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}=\frac{\text{d}f(x)}{\text{d}x}y+g(x) \tag{1}
\end{align}
for some arbitrary functions $f$ and $g$. This DE is invariant under the one parameter transformation group
\begin{align}
x_1=x+\mathcal{O}(\varepsilon^2),~~~~y_1=y+\varepsilon e^{f(x)}+\mathcal{O}(\varepsilon^2). \tag{2}
\end{align}
To solve (1) I am trying to use (2) to obtain the canonical coordinates $(u(x,y),v(x,y))$ which will allow me to write (1) in the simpler form
\begin{align}
\frac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}u}=G(u)
\end{align} 
for some function $G(u)$. By demanding transnational invariance in $v$, the quasi-linear equations satisfied by the canonical coordinates are
\begin{align}
X\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+Y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0 ~~~~\text{ and }~~~~ X\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}+Y\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=1.
\end{align}
From (2) we have that $X=0$ and $Y=e^{f(x)}$;
\begin{align}
e^{f(x)}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0,~~~~~~~e^{f(x)}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=1 \tag{3a, 3b}.
\end{align}
Equation (3a) says that $u=h(x)$ for some arbitrary function $h$ and equation (3b) says that $v=ye^{-f(x)}+k(x)$ for some arbitrary function $k$. If I now try to write (1) in terms of the canonical coordinates I get
\begin{align}
\frac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}u}=\frac{\text{d}v/\text{d}x}{\text{d}u/\text{d}x}&=\frac{\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}e^{-f}-y \frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}x}e^{-f}+\frac{\text{d}k}{\text{d}x}}{\frac{\text{d}h}{\text{d}x}}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{\bigg(\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}x}y+g\bigg)e^{-f}-y \frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}x}e^{-f}+\frac{\text{d}k}{\text{d}x}}{\frac{\text{d}h}{\text{d}x}}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{ge^{-f}+\frac{\text{d}k}{\text{d}x}}{\frac{\text{d}h}{\text{d}x}} \tag{4}.
\end{align}
Now I am not sure how I can write (4) as $\text{d}v/\text{d}u=G(h(x))$ for some function $G$. I think I am probably allowed to choose $k(x)=0$, but I still don't see how to get the results I am looking for.

Comment: Why not simply say that $e^{-f(x)}$ is an integrating factor and then find $\frac{d}{dx}(e^{-f(x)}y(x))=e^{-f(x)}g(x)$?

Comment: It is supposed to be an exercise in using Lie's one-parameter transformation technique to solve 1st order DE's, otherwise I would do it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not checked your whole procedure, but you would do the following, by assuming the most simple forms for $h$ and $k$:

$$u=h(x)=x \implies x(u,v)=u$$
$$v=y\exp(-f(x))+k(x)=y\exp(-f(x)) \implies y(u,v)=v\exp(f(u)).$$

Now, determine:

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial u}du+\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial v}dv}{\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial u}du+\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial v}dv}=\dfrac{\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial u}+\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial v}\dfrac{dv}{du}}{\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial v}\dfrac{dv}{du}}=\dfrac{v\exp(f(u))\dfrac{df}{du}+\exp(f(u))\dfrac{dv}{du}}{1+0\cdot\dfrac{dv}{du}}$$
$$=v\exp(f(u))\dfrac{df}{du}+\exp(f(u))\dfrac{dv}{du}$$

Using the ODE will give:

$$v\exp(f(u))\dfrac{df}{du}+\exp(f(u))\dfrac{dv}{du}=\dfrac{df}{du}v\exp(f(u))+g(u)$$

$$\implies\dfrac{dv}{du}=\exp(f(u))g(u)\implies v=c+\int\exp(f(u))g(u)du$$